# Including AngularJS related files in _Layout.Cshtml

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have included angular.min.js and related controller and Service files in _Layout.cshtml. It throws me an error and takes me to this link
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=OmsApp

However when I exclude Layout page and put those scripts in my child page, it works. Is there anything I am missing.

_OmsLayout.cshtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>_OmsLayout</title>
        <link href="~/Content/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/assets/css/OmsStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Controller/OmsController.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Service/OmsService.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="OmsApp" ng-controller="OmsCtlr">
           @RenderBody()
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Child Page

```
 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "ProductsList";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_OmsLayout.cshtml";
 }

<h2>ProductsList</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="~/Content/assets/images/DotNet_4.5.jpg" height="200" width="200" class="img-responsive CursorPointer" />
        <span class="CursorPointer" ng-click="ProductsCount();">Add to Cart</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="~/Content/assets/images/DotNet_4.5_2.jpg" height="200" width="200" class="img-responsive CursorPointer" />
        <span class="CursorPointer" ng-click="ProductsCount();">Add to Cart</span>
        <input type="button" ng-click="ProductsCount();" value="Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
var app = angular.module("OmsApp", []);
app.controller("OmsCtlr", function ($scope) {   $scope.ProductsCount = function () {
        alert("Hi");            
    };
});
```

Comment: What do you have set in `_ViewStart.cshtml` - are you using `_Layout.cshtml` or `_OmsLayout.cshtml`?

Comment: check `</body>` tag is missing in `Layout.cshtml` file

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
i am using _OmsLayout.cshtml.

Comment: Above works for me - but not including - `OmsService.js` - what are contents of that?

Comment: may be a spell mistake in `OmsController.js`

Comment: Hi James, Thank you very much, you were right, i had kept my service.js empty.
app.service("OmsService", function ($http, $q) {
});
Included this and it works now.

Comment: And thanks others as well for your efforts in helping me out.

Comment: Ok, glad its working.

Comment: Hi James P, you have any idea why it was working excluding the Service, it's been a week after i started Angular, any explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Best thing is to read how $injector works in Angular - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector